# LiveData owner definition potentially causing leak/retain

Tags: android, android-service, android-livedata

I am working on a project which uses a `LiveData` instance inside of a `Service`.
We initialize the Service as a bound service with our Activity, so we use `bindService()` and `unBindService()` to connect and disconnect. We invoke these functions in `onResume()` and `onPause()` respectively of the Activities lifecycle.

```
class TestActivity: Activity() {
    lateinit var ourService: OurService
    val serviceConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
         override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
            val binder = service as OurService.LocalBinder
            ourService = binder.getService()
            // Does this cause ourService to be retained beyond unbind the only client
            ourService.liveReading.observe(this@TestActivity, Observer {}
         }
    } 

    override fun onResume() {
           Intent(this, OurService::class.java).also { intent ->
            bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
         unBindService(serviceConnection)
    }
}
```

I have noticed that there is an edge case where I am getting more than one emission in the OurService's `LiveData` property. I wonder if this is because setting the owner to the activity, which survives a cycle of onPause/onResume, causes the Service to not be destroyed in the onPause case and therefore causes multiple observers to be assigned to the livedata after another cycle of onPause/onResume.

Comment: Does your service go though its `onDestroy`?

Answer (score 0):

Because I can't see your service code, so there are two points you should notice here

1. When you call unBindService it's not mean your service will be destroy, you could check service lifecycle here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service
2. When you call `ourService.liveReading.observe(this@TestActivity, Observer {}`
   you should notice, you are using LifecycleOwner of TestActivity. it mean  `liveReading` will stop receive data when TestActivity call DESTROYED state. In your case TestActivity don't call DESTROYED state (just call onPause) so `liveReading` still receive data, the question is what happen when your activity call onPause ? this is your answer

> When data changes while the LifecycleOwner is not active, it will not
> receive any updates.If it becomes active again, it will receive the
> last available data automatically